# How to make a very simple hand

Tags: modeling

I want to create hands for my model. But it must be in a cylinder shape. There are so many tutorials on YT but can't find one I want. Can anyone show me how to model like this?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a cube, create loopcuts on 2 axis with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (middle mouse button to increase or decrease the number of loopcuts):

[image]

Enable the *Proportional Editing* option and scale one side:

[image]

Select these faces and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Individual Faces*:

[image]

Once extruded, disable the *Proportional Editing* option and move the faces away from each others:

[image]

Enable the *LoopTools* addon, Select the wrist faces and right click > *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Extrude the cylinder:

[image]

Create loopcuts:

[image]